# arcpy copying fc to shp and appending fc to shp

Tags: python-2.7, arcpy

Using arcpy in python 2.7 I am trying to append data from a feature class to an empty shapefile.

env_export is the folder path.

I can create a new empty shapefile

```
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(env_export, "webmap_point.shp", "POINT")
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(env_export, "webmap_polyline.shp", "POLYLINE")
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(env_export, "webmap_polygon.shp", "POLYGON")
```

I can copy a fc to a new shapefile

```
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fc, env_export + "/webmap_polygon.shp")
```

But if I try to append a fc to a new or existing shapefile (columns are identical)

```
arcpy.Append_management(fc, env_export + "/webmap_polygon.shp")
```

I get the error:

```
ExecuteError: ERROR 000466: S:/PROJECTS/Workflow/GN_Coding/OA/03 GIS Projects - Coding Review/Geodatabase/DRS_survey_data.gdb/survey\loe_ply does not match the schema of target S:/PROJECTS/Workflow/GN_Coding/OA/03 GIS Projects - Coding Review/WebGIS_Exported/webmap_polygon.shp
```

Failed to execute (Append).

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of the [Append Tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/append.htm) is to "TEST" that the field names and types match. I've often found and even logged bugs where this test fails on identical feature classes. My best suggestion is to set the schema_type to "NO_TEST" and provide an empty string as field mapping. If you care to specify the exact field mapping, the easiest way to do this is to add the tool to a new model, set it up to run the way you'd want it to run in the script (provide all the input and target parameters and field mappings), and save the model. Then, export the model as a python script and copy the field mapping portion to your new script.[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'columns are identical' are the data types identical as well?

Also I believe you can use arcpy.CopyFeatures_management to create the feature class without first creating an empty template.